# How to remove ubuntu touch webapps from app store

Tags: ubuntu-touch, webapps

Does anyone know how to remove an app I've published for Ubuntu Touch from the app store?

It is no longer useful to have it there.

Comment: can you please clarify, what you mean by "remove from the app store" and what exactly you want to downgrade

Comment: I want to delete my own webapp from the Ubuntu app store.

Answer (score 0):

Is there not an option to delete your app on [Ubuntu MyApps](https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps/)?

Answer (score 0):

In https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/click-apps/ you can click the app in question, and in the left column, under the app logo, you can find an orange button to 'unpublish' it.

Users that already downloaded it, still have access to it and can redownload it in the app store, though, so that's maybe why you yourself can still see it there...